# Issuer URL using ADFS SSO SAML

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I am trying to integrate my web application with SAML SSO.

At first I create an application on Azure and enabled SAML and everything worked fine.
But recently we got a new client who has ADFS instead of azure cloud.

So he sent me the Issuer as the following `CN=${webapp.domain} O=${org.name}` instead of a valid URL.

How do I get the URL from that, or are they supposed to generate the URL a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access their metadata. The default location for ADFS metadata is https://server-name-goes-here/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml.

The entityID attribute corresponds to the issuer URL. Its default format is http://server-name-goes-here/adfs/services/trust.

If you can't access their metadata, ask them to send it to you.